# Heroku Error when running heroku commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Hi everytime I try to run a heroku command ex. `heroku run rails c --app <appname>` I am getting this error:

> ```
> !    Heroku client internal error.
> !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
> !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
>
>    Error:       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
> ```
>
> (Exc
>       n::Errors::SocketError)
>          Backtrace:   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.16.1/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:83:in
>   `connect'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.16.1/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:83:in`
>   initialize'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.16.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:344:in
>   `new'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.16.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:344:in`
>   socket'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.16.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:175:in
>   `request_kernel'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.16.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:101:in`
>   request'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.4/lib/heroku/api.rb:61:in
>   `request'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.4/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:9:in`
>   post_login'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:76:in `api_key'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:185:in`ask_for_credentials'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:217:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:80:in`get_credentials'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:70:in `password'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:17:in`api'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:40:in `api'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/config.rb:26:in`index'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:193:in `run'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in`start'
>                       C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `'
>
> ```
>    Command:     heroku config
>    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.30.3 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.2
> ```

What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same probleme, and the reason seems be the same: Your heroku toolbelt is outdated. Check it out: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1235

Get the current version in: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows

Answer (score 0):

From your command its seems like you want to run `Console` not application. If you have multiple environments (`staging` / `production` / etc) you need this command:

```
heroku run -a app-name console
```

If you only have a single environment and never setup staging or other environments you can just run:

```
heroku run console
```

For more details please check this https://github.com/nemrow/rails_app_cheatsheet/blob/master/heroku.rdoc

Heroku only runs in one environment at a time, [which is configured by the RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV environments variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#production-and-development-modes).

**Note:** Make sure that it is not in your `.gitignore` file. Commit and then push the changes to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku (along with many other responsible API providers) disabled its support for SSLv3 as of last Thursday: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/678